# inner join on null value

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql, sqlite

I'm not sure if i made a mistake in logic.

If i have a query and i do an inner join with a null value would i always get no results or will it ignore the join and succeed? example

```
user { id PK, name NVARCHAR NOT NULL, banStatus nullable reference }
```

if i write and u.banStatus i will receive no rows?

```
select * from user as u
join banstatus as b on u.banStatus=b.id
where id=1
```

Comment: NULL is undefined, so if we have NULL = NULL then result will always be false, as we are comparing two undefined values. I hope it answers your query

Comment: There's also an error in your query. The field `id` in your where clause is ambiguous - it could be `u.id` or `b.id`.

Comment: @Mark I tried a more complex logic version and suspected the problem. Thus writing that dummy query and not realizing the ambiguity

Answer (score 54):

You don't get the row if the join is null because NULL cannot be equal to anything, even NULL.

If you change it to a LEFT JOIN, then you will get the row.

With an inner join:

```
select * from user as u
join banstatus as b on u.banStatus=b.id

1, '1', 1, 'Banned'
```

With a left join:

```
select * from user as u
left join banstatus as b on u.banStatus=b.id

1, '1', 1, 'Banned'
2, 'NULL', , ''
```

Using this test data:

```
CREATE TABLE user (id int, banstatus nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO user (id, banstatus) VALUES
(1, '1'),
(2, 'NULL');

CREATE TABLE banstatus (id int, text nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO banstatus (id, text) VALUES
(1, 'Banned');
```

Comment: i didnt need test data or anything other then a conformation (yes you will not get rows) but good for future readers. +1&accept.

Answer (score 11):

When you do an `INNER JOIN`, `NULL` values do not match with anything. Not even with each other.  That is why your query is not returning any rows. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join))

Answer (score 8):

This is an inner joins on nulls (Oracle syntax):

```
select *
  from user
       uu
  join banstatus
       bb
    on uu.banstatus = bb.id
       or
       uu.banstatus is null and bb.id is null
```

Comment: so this joins when user and bb are null? interesting. id would never be null or 0. If i wrote `on uu.banstatus = bb.id or uu.banstatus is null` it will ignore it and join and not give me 0 rows? would this be the same as left join? Interesting. I no longer need the answer but if you feel like giving one i'll read.

Comment: No, this will not behave like a left join. If `bb.id` is never null, there will be no rows in the result with null `uu.banstatus`.

Comment: I know this is very late, but I suggest using parenthesis around your "or" clause.

Comment: The precedence of `and` and `or` is well-defined, with the former being higher. I much prefer the higher signal-to-noise ratio that results from avoiding unnecessary syntax. As a matter of principle, I would never write `1 + (2 * 3)` to clarify what I mean by `1 + 2 * 3` on the odd chance that someone without a basic grasp of arithmetic might someday try to make sense of my code. Novelists do not dumb down their prose to make their work more accessible to foreign readers. Similarly, I shouldn't have to dumb-down my code just to benefit someone who couldn't be bothered to learn SQL.

Comment: @KeithL, as a compromise, I've adjusted indentation to clarify intent.

Answer (score 3):

Nulls are not equal to any other value, so the join condition is not true for nulls. You can achieve the desired result by choosing a different join condition. Instead of

```sql
u.banStatus = b.id
```

use

```sql
u.banStatus = b.id OR (u.banStatus IS NULL AND b.id IS NULL)
```

Some SQL dialects have a more concise syntax for this kind of comparison:

```sql
-- PostgreSQL
u.banStatus IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b.id
```

```sql
-- SQLite
u.banStatus IS b.id
```